# C# Selenium add cookies from json file

Tags: c#, selenium, cookies

How do i add cookies to selenium in c#. like this python code add cookies from json file.

Python:

```
with open(js_cookie_path, "r") as cp:
    cookie = json.loads(cp.read())
    for c in cookie:
        driver.add_cookie(c)
```

c#

```
dynamic cookie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(js_cookie_path));
foreach (dynamic c in cookie) {
   Driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(c)
}
```